# Exception on sending multipart file request to eureka rest service end point

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, microservices, netflix-eureka

I am developing a file repository to store the pdf files. I am using eureka + spring boot which is in producer and consumer architecture. The client is having

```
public boolean uploadBooks(MultipartFile file, String fileLocation, String fileName) {
    boolean callResponse = false;
    try {
        if(!file.isEmpty()) {
            ByteArrayResource fileResource = new ByteArrayResource(file.getBytes()) {
                public String getFileName() {
                    return file.getOriginalFilename();
                }
            };
        LinkedMultiValueMap<String, Object> requestMap = new LinkedMultiValueMap<>();
        requestMap.add("file", fileResource);
        requestMap.add("repoLocation", fileLocation);
        requestMap.add("fileId", fileName);

        HttpHeaders requestHeader = new HttpHeaders();
        requestHeader.setContentType(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA);
        HttpEntity<LinkedMultiValueMap<String, Object>> requestEntity = new HttpEntity<LinkedMultiValueMap<String, Object>>(
                requestMap, requestHeader);
        System.err.println(requestEntity.getBody());
        System.err.println(uploadBooks);
        ResponseEntity<Boolean> response = restTemplate.exchange(uploadBooks,HttpMethod.POST, requestEntity,
                Boolean.class);
        callResponse = response.getBody();
        }
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }

    return callResponse;
}
```

and the rest end point is having

@PostMapping("/uploadFile")

```
public boolean uploadFile(@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file,
        @RequestParam("repoLocation") String repoLocation, @RequestParam("fileId") String fileId) {

    boolean process = false;
    try {
    System.out.println("---->"+fileId);
    process = fileServices.saveFile(file, repoLocation, fileId);
    } catch (RepoStorageException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    if (process) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;

}
```

when I am uploading file I am getting

> org.springframework.web.client.HttpClientErrorException$BadRequest: 400 null

exception. Please help me on writing the end point to handle the client request.

Error Stack trace

```
org.springframework.web.client.HttpClientErrorException$BadRequest: 400 null
at org.springframework.web.client.HttpClientErrorException.create(HttpClientErrorException.java:79)
at org.springframework.web.client.DefaultResponseErrorHandler.handleError(DefaultResponseErrorHandler.java:97)
at org.springframework.web.client.DefaultResponseErrorHandler.handleError(DefaultResponseErrorHandler.java:79)
at org.springframework.web.client.ResponseErrorHandler.handleError(ResponseErrorHandler.java:63)
at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.handleResponse(RestTemplate.java:777)
at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:735)
at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.execute(RestTemplate.java:669)
at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.exchange(RestTemplate.java:578)
at com.library.remoteservices.repository.LibraryFileRepository.uploadBooks(LibraryFileRepository.java:76)
at com.library.LibraryServiceDiscoveryClient.FileServiceController.uploadBooks(FileServiceController.java:28)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:215)
at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:142)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:102)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:895)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:800)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1038)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:942)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:998)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:901)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:660)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:875)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:92)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:93)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:200)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:199)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:490)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:408)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:770)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1415)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Comment: Your code looks fine. Returning a Boolean value from a Spring MVC annotated controller is not prescribed and may cause odd problems. Try changing the Boolean returns to simple strings like "successful" and "non successful" and see what happens.

Comment: @RandyCasburn I tried with String also, but I am getting same 400 null error. the below is going as request in requestEntity obj.  {file=[Byte array resource [resource loaded from byte array]], repoLocation=[/home/jayendrang/Data/UCI], fileId=[sampel]}. I able to upload the file by hitting with eureka assigned IP but when I am going through the client(rest template) I am getting this exception.

Comment: Are you using Zuul? How large are the files?

Comment: Could you please add full stack trace log?

Comment: @RandyCasburn currently not using Zuul and the file size is <5mb.  Simply eureka with spring boot. Actual flow is Consumer(boot client)<-->Eureka Discovery Server<--->Producer(Endpoint).

Comment: @JonathanJohx updated with stack trace log

Comment: I've take a look and looks good, I might help you later if you share your code on some repo. Perhaps it's in modeling that how you are saving the files multipart.

Comment: @JonathanJohx

https://github.com/Jayendrang/UCM_Final_Project/tree/master/LibraryServiceDiscoveryClient

https://github.com/Jayendrang/UCM_Final_Project/tree/master/LibraryServiceDiscoveryServer

https://github.com/Jayendrang/UCM_Final_Project/tree/master/LibraryFileRepositoryService

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Now-a-days there are projects like [Spring Content](https://paulcwarren.github.io/spring-content/) provide a very similar programming model for unstructured data (i.e. files, images, videos, etc) as Spring Data does for structured data.  Plus it allows you to associate those files with your Entities.

So (assuming you are using Spring Boot) you would add the following dependencies:

> pom.xml

```
   <!-- Java API -->
   <dependency>
      <groupId>com.github.paulcwarren</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-content-fs-boot-starter</artifactId>
      <version>0.4.0</version>
   </dependency>
   <!-- REST API -->
   <dependency>
      <groupId>com.github.paulcwarren</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-content-rest-boot-starter</artifactId>
      <version>0.4.0</version>
   </dependency>
```

Add the following attributes to your File entity so that content can be associated with it.

> File.java

```
@Entity
public class File {

   ...existing fields...

   @ContentId
   private UUID contentId;

   @ContentLength
   private long contentLength = 0L;

   // if you have rest endpoints
   @MimeType
   private String mimeType;

   ...
}
```

Create a `ContentStore` (the equivalent of your FileRepository but for your files):

> FileContentStore.java

```
@StoreRestResource(path="fileContents")
public interface FileContentStore extends ContentStore<File, UUID> {
}
```

When you run your application Spring Content will see the `FileContentStore` interface and the `spring-content-fs` dependency and inject a Filesystem implementation of this interface for you.  It will also see the `spring-content-rest` dependency and add an @Controller implementation that forwards GET, PUT, POST and DELETE REST requests onto `FileContentStore` as well.   This saves you from having to write any of the controller code you have above.  REST endpoints will be available at `/fileContents` so...

`curl -X POST -F "image=@/path/to/local/file.pdf" /fileContents/{fileId}`

will upload file.pdf and associate it with your file entity.  And:

`curl /fileContents/{fileId}` will fetch it again.

This programming model also creates an abstraction over the file storage implementation allowing you to choose any type of storage that Spring Content supports (currently, this is Filesystem, S3, JPA BLOBs, Mongo's Gridfs and Google Storage).  Your application code will stay the same regardless.

HTH

Comment: Excellent.  Glad to hear that @JayendranGurumoorthy

Comment: Also I found the issue with my code, I have to provide multipart resource object in the multivaluemap part instead i gave bytearray resource thats y i got null point exception while constructing the rest template object. Solution simply I called the multipartobject's resource method file.getResource();